# how to change active key for scripts

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

So am trying to change the active key for Lua script by using the key from keyboard
change from *scrolllock* to any key on keyboard like Alt+G or Num1 key ...

sorry for my bad English

```lua
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")then
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1)then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
        repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-11, 12)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(11, -10)
        Sleep(10)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: For a toggle-key LGS/GHUB can use only lock keys (ScrollLock, NumLock, CapsLock) and (only if you have Logitech gaming keyboard) keys G1,G2,...  It cannot use usual keys: letters. digits.  Or it can use any mouse button as a toggle key.  Do you have a mouse button you are currently not using in the game?